# ¿Cómo introducir en un struct char valores cuando esta dentro de un vector, lenguaje C?

Tags: c, struct

El código es el siguiente:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 20
#define MAX 30

typedef struct r{
    char Nombre [MAX+1]
}tR;

typedef tR tV[N];

int main() {
    tV Nombres={0};
    Nombres[0].Nombre="Pepe";
    return 0;

}
```

Cunado intento darle un valor al Nombres[0].Nombre me da error.
¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para asignar la cadena "Pepe" (una cadena literal `const char`) al array no puedes hacer uso del operador `=`, sino utilizar la función `strcpy` (no olvidarse de adjuntar la cabecera `string.h`)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 20
#define MAX 30

typedef struct r
{
    char Nombre[MAX+1];
} tR;

typedef tR tV[N];

int main()
{
    tV Nombres= {0};
    strcpy (Nombres[0].Nombre,"Pepe");    
    return 0;
}
```